# Java Generics: override method that differs in parameterized return type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overriding

I come from .Net and I'm pretty new to Java development so maybe that's a weird question:

I have a class hierarchy like:

```
Superclass implements GenericInterface<Superclass>
    ^
    |
 Subclass
```

where `GenericInterface` is pretty straight forward:

```
public interface GenericInterface<T> {
    OtherGenericInterface<T> getOther();
}
```

and `OtherGenericInterface` finally uses the type parameter:

```
public interface OtherGenericInterface<T> {
    List<Object> processType(T left, T right);
}
```

now when I try to implement the the interface in `Superclass` I simply return an anonymous type:

```
public class Superclass implements GenericInterface<Superclass> {
    @Override
    public OtherGenericInterface<Superclass> getOther() {
        return new OtherGenericInterface<Superclass>() {
            @Override
            public List<Object> processType(T left, T right) {
                ...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

That works fine so far but now I try to override the method in the `Subclass`:

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass (implements GenericInterface<Subclass>) {
    @Override
    public OtherGenericInterface<Subclass> getOther() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And in there, I can not override the method with my more specific return type. Even if I re-implement the interface and declare the method in the Superclass as final it is not possible.

So my question is:  Why isn't `OtherInterface<MoreSpecificType>` a more specific, or at least the same type (due to type erasure) because that would be the requirement to override the method right?.

Comment: `OtherInterface<Subclass>` isn't a subtype of `OtherInterface<Superclass>` for the same reason `ArrayList<Integer>` isn't a subtype of `ArrayList<Object>`

Comment: But its also not the same type?

Comment: No? Of course `OtherInterface<Subclass>` isn't *the same type* as `OtherInterface<Superclass>`...

Comment: Take a look at [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/1679537).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates a common misconception with Java generics - believing that a match of a class will also match subclasses (like types of parameters). That is not the case. Java generics are designed to ensure that the types match **exactly**. If you want wriggle room you must specify and define what room you want and how much.

Here's a version that allows you to do what you want by exactly specifying the signature as `<T extends Superclass>`. This may not be exactly what you are looking for but I hope it points you in the right direction.

```
public interface OtherGenericInterface<T> {

    List<Object> processType(T left, T right);
}

public interface GenericInterface<T> {

    OtherGenericInterface<T> getOther();
}

public class Superclass<T extends Superclass> implements GenericInterface<T> {

    @Override
    public OtherGenericInterface<T> getOther() {
        return new OtherGenericInterface<T>() {
            @Override
            public List<Object> processType(Superclass left, Superclass right) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    @Override
    public OtherGenericInterface<Subclass> getOther() {
        return null;
    }
}
```